# Objective-C coding guidelines

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

So in the guidelines it says:

> For code that will run on iOS only, use of automatically synthesized instance variables is preferred.
>
> When synthesizing the instance variable, use @synthesize var = var_; as this prevents accidentally calling var = blah; when self.var = blah; is intended.

```
 // Header file
@interface Foo : NSObject
// A guy walks into a bar.
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *bar;
@end

// Implementation file
@interface Foo ()
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *baz;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar = bar_;
@synthesize baz = baz_;
@end
```

Question is, does this apply to public variables only or private too? It's not really clear on the documentation, but would like to have some thoughts or perspective on why "if" this is only for public or private only? I think that it just makes sense for all public/private so that you don't mess up ivars and using the property

Comment: On a side note... Why would you have public instance variables?

Comment: Those aren't `private` ivars they are just not publicly visible... I think consistency is your friend. Also just because something is not publicly visible does not make it immune from you accidentally accessing something directly so of course it applies to both.

Comment: @Paul.s, Those definitely are private ivars. The `baz` property is "private" by being publicly invisible, but the backing ivar is just plain 'ol Private.

Comment: @MattWilding it's not private in the normal OOP sense. I can still access it from outside of this class.

Comment: @Paul.s You can call the synthesized getter without seeing it, but you only get the ivar if the getter returns it. It's impossible to directly access the ivar itself, so I would call that private in the normal OOP sense.

Comment: @MattWilding `Ivar object_getInstanceVariable(id obj, const char *name, void **outValue)` ?

Comment: @Paul.s ah, if the runtime's in bounds then the sky's the limit. Fair enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it particularly matters whether the variables in question are public or private. The practice of synthesizing under a different name makes it explicit when you are accessing the variable directly instead of using the generated accessor method.

Perhaps there's a different question underlying what you're asking: *should I typically access private ivars via the accessor or directly?* I think most skilled iOS devs tend to use accessors unless there is some particular reason not to (performance, avoiding side effects like KVO, etc.). Doing so is more future-proof and allows for flexibility in the underlying implementation. In a very small way, you're coding to an interface rather than an implementation.

It also might be worth pointing out that the default behavior of Clang is going to change in the future so that property-backing ivars are synthesized named `_foo` *by default*. Clearly the powers-that-be consider consider underscoring ivars to be a best-practice.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure much of it comes down to personal preferences, so here are mine, for what they are worth:

- I like to distinguish between public properties and "private" instance vars.
- Properties are always accessed through their accessors, except for initialization (and within a manually created accessor method, for obvious reasons). Hence, the underscore in the backing ivar is useful, and not really an issue in my daily use of the properties.
- Instance vars are used to hold state that is used internally in the methods, but not (directly) by other classes.
- I have become very fond of declaring my instance variables in the .m file. Nice, clean and easy (no switching back and forth between .h and .m to declare ivars).
- I find that this distinction helps me clear my mind and determine if a property is something outside agents should get and/or set directly (a property in .h), or if it is really just a help to get my method implementations to work (an ivar in .m).

I'd agree with Paul.s. that consistency is your friend, but to me, distinction is a friend, too.

Comment: Your distinctions are calling the same thing different names. A property is a property regardless of where it is declared. The ivar is the backing store which is generally generated for you with your @synthesize or in curly braces.